# Uncaught Error: Class 'PDFMerger' not found in

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy intentando usar esta libreria para unir varios PDFs [PDFMerger](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger)

He descargado y añadido todo a mi proyecto, pero sin embargo me lanza el error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDFMerger' not found in ... on line 32"

Aqui añado el fichero:

```
require'PDFMerger.php';
```

Y aqui es cuando lo uso:

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
foreach($ficheros as $fichero){
 $pdf->addPDF($fichero, 'all');
}
$pdf->merge('browser','result.pdf');
```

El fichero "PDFMerger.php" está en la misma carpeta desde donde lo llamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error se da porque como comentastes estan en la misma carpeta!
y estas intentando llamar a una clase PDFMerger;

puedes hacer una de estas 2 opciones

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
```

o comentar la linea 35

```
namespace PDFMerger;
```

y hay si podras hacer

```
$pdf = PDFMerger;
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias